# Twig: Slug with Regex in Twig?

Tags: regex, symfony, twig

I want to slugify a value, for example `"slugName = Spain & Italy"`

When I make my slug in TWIG `{{ slugName|slugify }}`, the result is `Spain_amp_Italy`

Is it possible to set a REGEX in Twig, so that my "&" for example will be translated in "and" ?
THANKS

Comment: Consider making your own twig filter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html It's a useful skill to master and will let your slugify exactly how you want.  Hint: Take a look at twig's slugify source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could concatenate multiple filters, and use a simple function `replace()`:

```
{{ slugName| replace({'&': 'and'}) | slugify }}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tested it with a string. Could you check what's the value of `slugName` for you?

Comment: When I make {{ '&tt&'| replace({'&': '-'})|slugify }} the value is "tt"

Comment: That's because `slugify` removes trailing and starting spaces or `-`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom function to do this

```
<?php
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_Filter('ampersand_to_and', function( $string = '' ) {

    return preg_replace('/(&amp;|&)/m', 'and', $string );
}));
```

and then you can use it as follows:

```
<p>{{ 'Spain & Italy'|ampersand_to_and }}</p>
<p>{{ 'Spain &amp; Italy'|ampersand_to_and }}</p>
```